#  How do I extract a foursquare access_token saved to DOM as a link so I can use it for API calls?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, oauth, access-token

The code looks like:

```
    var jsonUrl = url +"&callback=?";
//  $("#getJSON").click(function(){
            $.getJSON(
                jsonUrl,
                {
    dataType: "JSONP"
  },                
                function(json){ var items = [];
                var items = JSON.parse(json);
                alert(items);


                    $("#result").html("<h3>" + result + "</h3>");



                }  
        );
```

also tried

```
$.ajax({

    type: 'GET',   

    url: url,
    key: $('#access_token'),
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data){ $('.result').html(data);
        processData: false,

        alert(jQuery.data( document.access_token ));
         alert(data[0].text);},
    error: function() {
        console.log('Uh Oh!'); },
    jsonp:'onJSONPLoad'

    });
```

Essentially if I'm in Firebug and look at the net objects I see the status 200

If I click on the JSON tab I can see my `access_token`, but how do I extract it from there so I can use for API calls?

Comment: Don't save it to dom but to variable?

Comment: Any suggestions on how to do so?

Answer (score 0):

```
var jsonUrl = url +"&callback=?";
var access_token;

$("#getJSON").click(function() {
    $.getJSON(jsonUrl, { dataType: "JSONP" }, function(json){ 
        ...
        access_token = json.access_token;
        ...
    });
});

// do something with your access_token ?
```

Did i understand your question right? You can assign the the access_token to a variable and then do what you want with it in your code, can't you?

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  jsonp: 'callback',
  url: url,
  success: function (json) {
    console.log(json.access_token);
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes, definitely understood the question, but as I try to implement a call for the access token later in the script (even with this example,) it prints "oauth_token=undefined&format=json" For example if I were to add an alert(access_token); it doesn't give the auth_token.

Comment: Added one more code example, can you try it? What it prints in console now?

Comment: Same, Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type application/json.
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Comment: Got a chin scratcher here, I feel like I'm so close! : p Been battling for hours. Everything is happening correctly just have to pass that access_token from the Dom to a Variable I can then Store.